# Angular2/Typescript: How to get an array of objects through Pipe?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, typescript

I'm new to Angular2/Typescript and have been stuck on this for almost a day. I'm sure this must be something simple that I'm missing:

This is my view: **noticias.html**

```
<ion-list id="NewsList" no-margin>
    <ion-item no-padding *ngFor="let item of newsData | newsfilter">
    ...
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I need to filter that list in this **newsfilter pipe**.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'newsfilter'
})

export class NewsfilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(array: any[]) {        
        console.log(array.length);        
    }

}
```

Right now, when I console.log the array, I get an array with a couple of objects in it, which is what I would expect.

[console.log(array)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnevy.png)

However, and this is what's confusing me, when I console.log(array.length) I get "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'array.length'). I also can't access any keys in these objects like array[0].id, for example.

Can someone please help in explaining what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the `newsData` field cannot be `undefined` or `null`?

Your filter should be able to handle this possibility.

```
transform(array: any[]) {

    if (!array) return;      
    console.log(array.length);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a signature on your transform method

```
transform(value: any, args? any): any {
  console.log(value.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a colleague of mine had the same problem lately. How and when do you set the value of `newsData` and what's the initial value here?

The thing is, that a pipe is executed immediately when the view renders (afaik). Meaning, that the value of `newsData` probably could be undefined when the pipe is executing the first time and that's ok. If I remember correctly, it executes even before `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook is called.

Adding an if to the pipe checking for an existing value should be the solution. After you assign the real value to `newsData`, the pipe is executed automatically again and the value should be correct.

EDIT: To check this, `console.log('## array:', array);` should be shown two times in the console. First with `## array: undefined` and second with the correct value.